# $_POST['variable'] doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, post, http-post

I have an html page with  some select and textarea, which are not surrounded by `<form>` tag, and a button which run the following script:

```
function sendReservationData(){
    var partenzaSel = $( "#selPartenza" ).val();
    var partenzaTArea = $( "#textP" ).val();
    var destinazioneSel = $( "#selDestinazione" ).val();
    var destinazioneTArea = $( "#textD" ).val();
    var nPasseggeri = $( "#selPasseggeri" ).val();

    var baseURL = window.location.origin;
    var serviceURL = baseURL + window.location.pathname;    

    $.post(serviceURL, {'partenzaSel' : partenzaSel, 'partenzaTArea' : partenzaTArea, 'destinazioneSel' : destinazioneSel, 'destinazioneTArea' : destinazioneTArea, 'nPasseggeri' : nPasseggeri},
         function(response){
            location.reload();
         }   
    ); }
```

I used that way to build the url because I'm working on xamp and when I'll finish, I'll must upload my code in a univerity server in which I don't know the complete path or the right url of the website. 
When I click the button, I want to use the variables that I send with the script that I showed you for starting a transaction and do some query to the database so, in order to see if I'm able to collect the data from select and textarea, in the same page, after the button, I wrote the following code which will be completed with the interaction with the database.

```
 <?php
$Partenza = $partenzaSel = $partenzaTArea = $destinazioneSel = $destinazioneTArea = $nPasseggeri = "";
if (isset($_POST['partenzaSel']) and isset($_POST['partenzaTArea']) and isset($_POST['destinazioneSel']) and isset($_POST['destinazioneTArea']) and isset($_POST['nPasseggeri']) ){

     $partenzaSel = $_POST['partenzaSel'];
     $partenzaTArea = $_POST['partenzaTArea'];
     $destinazioneSel = $_POST['destinazioneSel'];
     $destinazioneTArea = $_POST['destinazioneTArea'];
     $nPasseggeri = $_POST['nPasseggeri'];

     echo $partenzaSel + $partenzaTArea + $destinazioneSel + $destinazioneTArea + $nPasseggeri + "prova";
}                                                   
?>
```

The echo shows me anything, so my attempt to take variables saved in javascript does not work and I'm not able to use that values to continue my work. What I'm wrong? How can I do? Thank you for help.

Comment: As `location.reload()` will reload/refresh the page from the server it is not surprising that you do not see the echoed values

Comment: start off doing "var_dump($_POST);" and see which (if any) of the variables are getting through and what their values are. 
Although i feel that because you are reloading the location, thats not actually submitting the form. you are sending the information to the script, its handling it, and then you're refreshing the page.

if you were to make it write the variables to a text file im sure you'll find they are getting there

Comment: Replace `location.reload()` with `console.log(response)` an look at the browser debugger log

Comment: Also in PHP the concatenator is a `.` dot and NOT a `+` plus sign!

Comment: I tried to see the console. It showed to me my source code plus the response of the echo and there are the values that I want. I don't know why the page doesn't print the echo, but in my final code I don't need it. I only want the values of the variables to interact with the database and it seems that the variables are not empy after the click, so I can try to continue my work and see if the queries that I will write will works.

Comment: @ennio the echo does not work because PHP is a backend script, jquery is a front end script. 
PHP happens BEFORE the page loads, if you want it to display the response, you need a jquery to put the response: i'll put it below

Comment: Kindly can you update the complete `form`  code also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are expecting PHP (server side coding) to handle something AFTER the page is loaded, when you reload the page it is like nothing is sent to it, either send it as a form or handle the PHP response with JQuery and display it on the page. 
JQuery is active on the browser side and functions as long as the page is open, PHP processes BEFORE the page is sent to the browser from the web server.

make the php side:

```
`print json_encode($partenzaSel . $partenzaTArea . $destinazioneSel . $destinazioneTArea . $nPasseggeri . "prova");`
```

Then with the front jquery:

```
$.post(serviceURL, {'partenzaSel' : partenzaSel, 'partenzaTArea' : partenzaTArea, 'destinazioneSel' : destinazioneSel, 'destinazioneTArea' : destinazioneTArea, 'nPasseggeri' : nPasseggeri},
     function(response){
        data = JSON.parse(response);
        $("#responseDiv").text(data);
     }   
); }
```

and make a div with the id "responseDiv" on the webpage so it can place the text in that box.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove `location.reload()` from your javascript and change your php to the following.

```
<?php
$Partenza = $partenzaSel = $partenzaTArea = $destinazioneSel = $destinazioneTArea = $nPasseggeri = "";
if (isset($_POST['partenzaSel']) and isset($_POST['partenzaTArea']) and isset($_POST['destinazioneSel']) and isset($_POST['destinazioneTArea']) and isset($_POST['nPasseggeri']) ){

     $partenzaSel = $_POST['partenzaSel'];
     $partenzaTArea = $_POST['partenzaTArea'];
     $destinazioneSel = $_POST['destinazioneSel'];
     $destinazioneTArea = $_POST['destinazioneTArea'];
     $nPasseggeri = $_POST['nPasseggeri'];

     echo $partenzaSel . $partenzaTArea . $destinazioneSel . $destinazioneTArea . $nPasseggeri . "prova";
     exit;
}                                                   
?>
```

this should now exit the script with an output if it receives the data.

Comment: Dont see how this will improve anything

Comment: it doesn't improve anything

Comment: where do you see your output of php? remember you are sending ajax request either you use a developer tool or you console.log the response to see the output.

Comment: I've used console.log. The echo doesn't work, but the variables are saved. I don't need the echo, it was just a try, so I'm trying to use these variables with the database in order to see if it works like I need.

Answer (score 1):

I have given a try:

As no `form code` is provided so i just replaced the test data in `javascript`.

**Problem Reason** as you are using `+` instead of `.` in php code for final `echo` so due to this `echo` response the `0` and i think due to that `javascript post callback` not working it treats that as `failure` or `error`

and yes @yunus-saha is right even i don't understand using of this code `location.reload()` . You can use either `console.log` or `append or text` function of jquery.

**HTML**

```
<html>
   <body>   
     <form method='post' >

     <input type='submit' value='submit' onclick='sendReservationData();' />
     </form>

   <script type='text/javascript'  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"> 
    </script>
   <script type='text/javascript' >
        function sendReservationData(){
            var partenzaSel = 'partenzaSel';
            var partenzaTArea = 'partenzaTArea';
            var destinazioneSel = 'destinazioneSel';
            var destinazioneTArea = 'destinazioneTArea';
            var nPasseggeri = 'nPasseggeri';

           var baseURL = window.location.origin;
           var serviceURL = baseURL + window.location.pathname;    

       $.post('php3.php',{"partenzaSel" : partenzaSel, "partenzaTArea" : partenzaTArea, "destinazioneSel" : destinazioneSel,"destinazioneTArea" : destinazioneTArea, "nPasseggeri" : nPasseggeri}, function (data){
        console.log(data);
        });
       }
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
     $Partenza = $partenzaSel = $partenzaTArea = $destinazioneSel = 
         $destinazioneTArea = $nPasseggeri = "";
      if (isset($_POST['partenzaSel']) and isset($_POST['partenzaTArea']) and 
        isset($_POST['destinazioneSel']) and isset($_POST['destinazioneTArea']) and 
        isset($_POST['nPasseggeri']) ){
       $partenzaSel = $_POST['partenzaSel'];
       $partenzaTArea = $_POST['partenzaTArea'];
       $destinazioneSel = $_POST['destinazioneSel'];
       $destinazioneTArea = $_POST['destinazioneTArea'];
       $nPasseggeri = $_POST['nPasseggeri'];
       echo $partenzaSel .'--'. $partenzaTArea  .'--'.  $destinazioneSel  .'--'.  
      $destinazioneTArea  .'--'.  $nPasseggeri  .'--'.  "prova";
  }                                                   
 ?>
```

[image]